# JS - Is there a case where !!x and x don't represent the same logical value

Tags: javascript, boolean

I was refactoring my code and I fell on a few lines where I was using double negation in the `if` conditions.

It got me thinking, are there any cases in javascript where `if (!!x)` wont resolve to the same condition as `if (x)`?

**Note:** I'm not talking about !!x !== x, I mean do they represent different logical values. In other words, is there a situation where these 2 expressions won't have the same outcome.

```
x ? true : false;
!!x ? true : false;
```

Comment: Like `x = new Boolean(true)`?

Comment: Technically if `x = new Boolean(true)` then `!!x !== x`.  However, both `if (x)` and `if (!!x)` will evaluate to `true`.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you asking? There's two distinct questions you've asked, `!!x !== x` and `if(x)`. Those are _not_ the same thing.

Comment: @jhpratt I edited the question, also I never said anything about `!!x` and `x` being equal.

Comment: @TheGirrafish It's literally the title of your question

Comment: @jhpratt That's a fair point, lemme change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case where `x = NaN`, `!!x` is not equal to `x`. Here is a test:

```js
var x = NaN;
if(!!x == x) {
  console.log("!!x is equal to x");
} else if (!!x !== x) {
  console.log("!!x is not equal to x");
}
```

However, their logical value is the same, which means they will perform equally inside a logical test. Thus, irrespective of the nature of x, `if(!!x)` is the same as `if(x)`, and hence every instance of `if(!!x)` can be safely replaced with `if(x)`;

```js
var x = NaN;
if(!!x) {
  console.log("True");
} else if(x) {
  console.log("False");
}
```

```js
var x = NaN;
if(x) {
  console.log("True");
} else if(!!x) {
  console.log("False");
}
```

I made two snippets (one in which I swapped the tests) such that the if statement does not stop at the first test if it is valid.

Comment: The answer is no, there can't be a variable x where the logical value of `!!x` is different from that for `x`.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't.

Every value in JS is either falsy or truthy:

- almost all objects are truthy
- all numbers expect 0 are truthy
- all strings expect the empty string are truthy
- 0 is falsy
- empty string is falsy
- undefined and null are falsy

!!expr will turn a falsy value to false and a truthy value to true. It is essentially a conversion of expr to a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already answered, all values are falsy or truthy, so there is no variable x such as x != !!x.

However, if you x is not a variable, but is a logical unit such as `(a || b)`, there exist cases where your yet to be evaluated x does not equal !!x.

From the [MDN Javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) :

```
o5 = 'Cat' || 'Dog'      // t || t returns "Cat"
o6 = false || 'Cat'      // f || t returns "Cat"
```

If you evaluate `!('Cat' || 'Dog')`, the return value would be `false`, then you get `!!('Cat' || 'Dog')` which will of course return `true`.

So yeah, in that case not only you can get `x !== !!x` ; you can also get `x != !!x`